# How to predict out of sample values using Spark (JAVA API)

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-ml

I'm quite new to Spark and I need to use the JAVA api. Our goal is to serve predictions on the fly, where the user is going to provide a few of the variables, but not the label or the goal variable, of course.

But the model seems to need the data to be split in training data and test data for training and validation.

How can I get the prediction and the RMSE for the out of the sample data, that the user will query on the fly?

```
 Dataset<Row>[] splits = df.randomSplit(new double[] {0.99, 0.1});
        Dataset<Row> trainingData = splits[0];
        Dataset<Row> testData = df_p;
```

My out of sample data has the following format (where 0s is data the user cannot provide)

```
IMO,PORT_ID,DWT,TERMINAL_ID,BERTH_ID,TIMESTAMP,label,OP_ID
0000000,1864,80000.00,5689,6060,2020-08-29 00:00:00.000,1,2
```

'label' is the result I want to predict.

This is how I used the models:

```
// Train a GBT model.
        GBTRegressor gbt = new GBTRegressor()
                .setLabelCol("label")
                .setFeaturesCol("features")
                .setMaxIter(10);

// Chain indexer and GBT in a Pipeline.
        Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(new PipelineStage[] {assembler, gbt, discretizer});

// Train model. This also runs the indexer.
        PipelineModel model = pipeline.fit(trainingData);

// Make predictions.
        Dataset<Row> predictions = model.transform(testData);

// Select example rows to display.
        predictions.select("prediction", "label", "weekofyear", "dayofmonth", "month", "year", "features").show(150);

// Select (prediction, true label) and compute test error.
        RegressionEvaluator evaluator = new RegressionEvaluator()
                .setLabelCol("label")
                .setPredictionCol("prediction")
                .setMetricName("rmse");
        double rmse = evaluator.evaluate(predictions);
        System.out.println("Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) on test data = " + rmse);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear if you want to get the RMSE for test data or other data. If it's about the test data, you already got the RMSE. If you want some other data to validate, then you can create another dataset and make predictions on that.

Comment: sorry, I want both the prediction and the RMSE for the out of sample data. Does that make sense?

Comment: This is predictions. This dataset will have a column named `predictions`.   ` Dataset<Row> predictions = model.transform(testData);`  Still your question is not clear.

Comment: how can I create a TestData dataframe of out of sample values? my current test data contains data from the split of the previously captured data. I need to run the predictions for points in the future, that are not in the capture data dataframe.

Comment: The same way you created the `df` before splitting it into two.

Comment: yes, but how can I deal with value that are 'missing'. Let's say, I want my customer to find out what the 'label' figure will be in 2 months from now. she cannot give me an initial 'label' value. I added 1 in this example because I'm taking the log of the label column in the training data. so I'm sending 0 to the model, and the RMSE gets really huge.

Comment: The 'label` is not used for prediction. Only the feature columns are used by the model to do the prediction. If you get a huge RMSE, that could mean the model is biased to the training set population. On another note, you can't find RMSE for set of unknown labels. RMSE is to find the accuracy of the model. That needs to be done with known data.

Comment: thanks, Pubudu! It is clear now. RMSE of the training set population is not big really. So it doesn't make sense to calculate RMSE of the out of sample predictions?

Comment: Yes. To calculate the RMSE, you need to use a known data set similar to the training data you used with known labels.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219721/discussion-between-draconar-and-pubudu-sitinamaluwa).